# Tabu Search Heuristic Implementation in C#

Tags: c#, framework, optimization

I'm looking for a C# implementation of a TabuSearch Metaheuristic Framework. 
Like the Basic Heuristic Implementation with interfaces to adapt to my needs for providing custom aspiration criteria and neighborhood search.

Could you provide References ?

In the best case the provided references provides example code for problems like the TSP or another combinatorial optimization problem.

Best regards and have a nice day.
Cookies for best answer

Comment: Are you looking for a framework/library to use – or for example code/snippets?

Comment: Hi Izzy, both would be interesting. I take it all.

Comment: That was diplomatic :) Just to let you know: the latter are off-topic here when asked "on its own", see: [Is asking for sample, illustrative code on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185) Good luck then!